# Do we need more Mutants and masterminds edition tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, game-systems

With the release of M&M 3rd Edition, we have an issue with having most questions be about 2nd, and a few about 3rd, but no tag to differentiate between the two systems with significant differences.  There's also the little played 1st edition of Mutants and masterminds, but right now, all of these games are lumped under the single tag [mutants-and-masterminds].  Do we need more tags to differentiate between these systems, and if so, what should they be?  [mutants-and-masterminds-xth] is too long to be a tag.

I'm not certain as to the differences between 1st and 2nd, but between 2nd and 3rd, while many things remain the same, there has been a major shift in the system with many of the names remaining the same.  There are now 8 ability scores instead of 6, instead of defense, there's parry and dodge as separate things, the skill list has been simplified and the individual skills broadened, and there are fewer effects.  A whole lot of the terminology is the same though, even though it's applied differently, so it would be easy to mistake some 3rd edition questions as 2nd (and vice versa).

Comment: You could use [mnm-xth] or [m-and-m-xth] or something, like how D&D has the [[tag:dungeons-and-dragons]] tag and the [dnd-Xe] tags. I'm not sure what acronym the M&M community is inclined to use though.

Comment: How different are the individual editions?

Comment: terminology confusion is a very good reason to have multiple tags. That's what we're looking for.

Comment: I agree with @waxeagle. From the description you've given of the changes between 2nd and 3rd editions, I would say it would be appropriate to have separate tags to distinguish the different editions

Answer (score 6):

There are two important questions.

The first is how many questions we get in general in the tag. Right now that number is 17.

The second is how different the editions are. Not being familiar with the game I'm unable to comment on this.

However, with the relative dearth of questions on this particular system, I'd favor specifying edition in the question and not creating a tag. I can't point to a particular threshold, but I'd guess 50 questions would probably be a good start.

The only exception I'd be interested in making here is if the editions were *so dramatically different* that information for 1st, 2nd, and 3rd edition are not helpful to players of other editions.

From the sounds of it, this could very well be the case between second and third editions. It would be worth seeing *if* this becomes an issue and retagging with mutants-and-masterminds-3e *if* we see it becoming an issue in the tag.

Comment: This is about what I was going to say, but couldn't sort out the words. Basically, "**Maybe**, tell us more?"