# Rename the M&M edition tags to be properly hyphenated

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

As a result of [Do we need more Mutants and masterminds edition tags?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3659/do-we-need-more-mutants-and-masterminds-edition-tags) we now have a couple of Mutants and Masterminds edition tags: [m-and-m2e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/m-and-m2e) and [m-and-m3e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/m-and-m3e).

By the convention of basically every other edition tag on the site, those should be [m-and-m-2e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/m-and-m-2e) and [m-and-m-3e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/m-and-m-3e), with that extra hyphen before the edition number. The closeness prevents me from doing a retag. Could these be renamed?

Comment: The "too similar" filter preventing even high-rep users from fixing things like this is a headache.

Comment: I keep seeing this question on the meta question list and thinking someone asked a question about candy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The lack of hyphen makes me cry and needs to be fixed. I support this. Vote for me!

Comment: And then we voted for SSD in a different way a few months later and he came back to fix the thing. Thanks!